# Pygame, how to draw a shape to the screen and delete the previous surface?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I have this code, and it does what it's supposed to fine. What I want it to do is randomly scale the square by different amounts, which it does. My problem lies with the blit function, my square only seems to scale up because blit doesn't delete the old shape it just copies the new one to the surface.

How can I make the shape expand and shrink, and not just expand?

My code:

```
import sys, random, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

w = 640
h = 480

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
morphingShape = pygame.Surface((20,20))
morphingShape.fill((255, 137, 0)) #random colour for testing
morphingRect = morphingShape.get_rect()

def ShapeSizeChange(shape, screen):
    x = random.randint(-21, 20)
    w = shape.get_width()
    h = shape.get_height()
    if w + x > 0 and h + x > 0:
        shape = pygame.transform.smoothscale(shape, (w + x, h + x))
    else:
        shape = pygame.transform.smoothscale(shape, (w - x, h - x))
    shape.fill((255, 137, 0))
    rect = shape.get_rect()
    screen.blit(shape, rect)
    return shape


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    morphingShape = ShapeSizeChange(morphingShape, screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On every frame (each iteration of the While loop) you should erase the screen. By default the screen (window) color is black, so you should clear the screen by calling `screen.fill( (0,0,0) )`. Below is the full code, now working as you expect:

```
import sys, random, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

w = 640
h = 480

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
morphingShape = pygame.Surface((20,20))
morphingShape.fill((255, 137, 0)) #random colour for testing
morphingRect = morphingShape.get_rect()

# clock object that will be used to make the animation
# have the same speed on all machines regardless
# of the actual machine speed.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def ShapeSizeChange(shape, screen):
    x = random.randint(-21, 20)
    w = shape.get_width()
    h = shape.get_height()
    if w + x > 0 and h + x > 0:
        shape = pygame.transform.smoothscale(shape, (w + x, h + x))
    else:
        shape = pygame.transform.smoothscale(shape, (w - x, h - x))
    shape.fill((255, 137, 0))
    rect = shape.get_rect()
    screen.blit(shape, rect)
    return shape


while True:
    # limit the demo to 50 frames per second
    clock.tick( 50 );

    # clear screen with black color
    # THIS IS WHAT WAS REALLY MISSING...
    screen.fill( (0,0,0) )

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    morphingShape = ShapeSizeChange(morphingShape, screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Note that just the addition of `screen.fill( (0,0,0) )` solves your question.